# Three.js How to apply raycast tolerance

Tags: three.js

That is, how to figure out intersections using not only the mouse position but a rectangular  3 x 3 or 5 x 5 area ? Have I to create these 8 or 16 xtra rays and calculate intersections for all objects? Could be this a Three feature request ?

I want some degree of freedom when I want to pick an object. 
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you have more than one ray, how do you intend to differentiate between more than one object that can get picked?

Comment: I test the first ray (from camera position to proyected mouse xy). If fails (no intersections) I try 8 diferent rays moving the initial mouse cords 1 pixel following a rectangular shape, that is,adding : -1,1 / 0,1 / 1,1 / 1,0 / 1,-1 / 0,-1/ -1,-1 / -1,0 to the current mouse pos. In case I get some intersection I stop the loop and return an intersected object (the first if three give me more than one). If fail I try the same technique usng a 3x3 rectangle. So, I can  select an object if my mouse is 3 pixels near the boundary of an object.  My question: is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: if you want to select closest object out of fixed set, you can select by max dot product of normalized directions to each object and to clicked pixel, for example. that's way less precise than raycasting, though.

Comment: this doesn't make much sense to me, but it seems like the loop would be the only way to do this. What does your scene look like, how come you anticipate so many misses, i thought that rays pick stuff most of the time. As in, you will either always terminate on your first ray, or youre going to do a hell of a lot of extra computation to compare results

Comment: Westlangey || MR.Doob opinion would be appreciated

Comment: What happens when you select a pixel that's right between two different objects? The neighbor to the right is one object, the neighbor to the left is another. Out of A B, NULL which one is the right answer? I think the fact that Westlangey || MR.Doob circumnavigated this question speaks volumes of how little sense it makes :)

Comment: In this case NULL would be the right. But in the most of cases your mouse is near 1 object and if the distance is at 1 or 2 pixels to the object boundary  every user would want to have the object selected.